# How to access a shared file from multiple threads most effectively?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, file-io

I'm developing a small web-app whose servlets periodically get access to a shared resource which is a simple text-file on the server side holding some lines of mutable data. Most of the time, servelts just read file for the data, but some servelts may also update it, adding new lines to the file or removing and replacing existing lines. Although file contents is not updated very often, there is still little chance for the data inconsistency and file corruption if two or more servlets decide to read and write to file at the same time.

**The first goal is to make the file reading/writing safe**. For this purpose, I've created a helper FileReaderWriter class providing some static methods for thread-safe file access. The read and write methods are coordinated by `ReentrantReadWiteLock`. The rule is quite simple: multiple threads may read from file at any time as far as no other thread is writing to it at the same time.

```java
public class FileReaderWriter {
    private static final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public static List<String> read(Path path) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        rwLock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            list = Files.readAllLines(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            rwLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void write(Path path, List<String> list) {
        rwLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            Files.write(path, list);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, every servelt may use the above method for file reading like this:

```java
String dataDir = getServletContext().getInitParameter("data-directory");
Path filePath = Paths.get(dataDir, "test.txt");
ArrayList<String> list  = FileReaderWriter.read(filePath);
```

Similarly, writing may be done with `FileReaderWriter.write(filePath, list)` method. Note: if some data needs to be replaced or removed (which means fetching the data form a file, processing it and writing updated data back to a file), then the whole code paths for this operation should be locked by `rwLock.writeLock()` for atomicity reasons.

**Now, when access to a shared file seems to be safe (at least, I hope so), the next step is to make it fast**. From the scalability perspective, reading a file at every user's request to the servlet doesn't sound reasonable. So, what I thought of is to read the contents of file into `ArrayList` (or other collection) only once during the context initialization time and then share this ArrayList (not the file) as a context-scoped data-holder attribute. Then a context-scoped attribute can be shared by servlets with the same locking mechanism as described above and the contents of the updated ArrayList may be independently stored back to the file on some regular basis.

Another solution (in order to avoid locking) would be to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (or some other collection from `java.util.concurrent` package) for holding a shared data and designate a single-threaded `ExecutorService` to dump its contents into a file when needed. I also heard of Java Memory-Mapped Files for mapping the entire file into internal memory, but not sure if such approach is appropriate for this particular situation.

So, could anybody, please, guide me thorough the most effective ways (maybe, suggesting some other alternatives) to solve the problem with a shared file access, provided that the writing to a file is quite infrequent and the contents of it is not expected to exceed a dozens of lines.

Comment: The simple approach is using synchronized methods when accessing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain your real problem, only your current attempt then, is difficult to provide a good solution.

Your approach has two serious problems:

**Problem 1: concurrency**

> a shared resource which is a simple text-file on the server side
>   holding some lines of mutable data

90% of the solution to a problem is a good data structure. A mutable file it's not. Even popular database engines have important concurrency limitations (eg. *SQLite*), don't try to reinvent the wheel.

**Problem 2: horizontal scalability**

Even if he solves his local concurrency problems (eg. synchronous methods), you won't be able to deploy multiple instances (nodes/servers) of your application.

**Solution 1: use the right tool for the job**

You don't explain exactly the nature of your (data management) problem but probably any [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database will do you good (reading about [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) can be a good starting point).

**(Bad) solution 2: use [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html)**

If for some reason you insist on doing what you indicate, use low level file locks using [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html). You will only have to deal with partial file locks and even these can be distributed horizontally. You won't have to worry about synchronizing other resources either, as file-level locks will suffice.

**(Limited) solution 3: in memory structure**

If you don't need horizontal scalability, you can use a shared in memory structure like [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) but you will lose the horizontal scalability and you could lose transactions if you do not persist the information before an application stop.

**Conclusion**

Although there are more exotic distributed data models, using a database for even a single table may be the best and simplest solution.

Comment: I would totally agree, from the perspective of horizontal scalability, using an in-memory concurrent structure for "caching" data no longer seems to be an option (being honest, I just didn't look so far ahead). As for the database,using MySQL was my first intention, though I was a bit reluctant about the idea to create a database just for the purpose of storing a couple or maybe more mutable properties. Anyway, thank you for your remarks and suggestions (in particular, for the **MongoDB** which I find now very attractive tool).